# Getting "string index out of range" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is from CodingBat and the question is: Return True if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of times in the given string.

I have the solution but it states that the string index is out of range. I do not really understand what this means since I am new to python.

```py
def cat_dog(str):
  dogCount = 0
  catCount = 0

  length = len(str)

  if length > 6:
    for i in range(length-1):
      if str[i]== 'd' and str[i+1]== 'o'  and str[i+2]== 'g':
        dogCount +=1
      elif str[i]== 'c' and str[i+1]== 'a' and str[i+2]== 't':
        catCount +=1
  else:
    return False

  if dogCount == catCount:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Expect either a true or false based on the function results

Comment: you call `str[i+2]` and your loop goes up to `length-1` so that is why you are getting the error

Comment: don't use `str` as a variable. This is a python keyword

Answer (score 0):

String index out of range error means you're trying to access a letter beyond the length of the string. This is happening in your for loop because when `i = length - 2`, `str[i+2]` becomes `str[length]` which is beyond the length of the string. Also, you should change `if length > 6` to `if length >= 6`. Try this code:

```
def cat_dog(string):
  dogCount = 0
  catCount = 0

  length = len(string)

  if length >= 6:
    for i in range(length-2):
      if string[i]== 'd' and string[i+1]== 'o' and string[i+2]== 'g':
        dogCount +=1
      elif string[i]== 'c' and string[i+1]== 'a' and string[i+2]== 't':
        catCount +=1
  else:
    return False

  if dogCount == catCount:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: you should also make changes to JacobIRR comment

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to continuously check the string to see if it contains either of the words replacing the first occurrence until there is no more:

```
def cat_dog(string):
    dogCount = 0
    catCount = 0

    while "dog" in string:
        dogCount += 1
        string = string.replace("dog", "", 1)

    while "cat" in string:
        catCount += 1
        string = string.replace("cat", "", 1)

    if dogCount == catCount:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```